# How to switch images with jQuery using .load()?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, image

I'm making a button for a wordPress-plugin. When you click on it, it should change and save a cookie on the computer for later use. The cookie will be saved, and if I refresh the page, the square is becoming a triangle.

My problem is, I want the picture to upate when the user clicks on it, so it's refreshes #MyDiv -> checks the cookie MyCookie -> shows the correct picture (triangle.png or square.png). I have tried searching around for a few day now, but can't seem to find a right answer. I have tried .html() as well, and it updates the picture, but then I can't click on it before page has been refreshed. I hope you can and will help me.

Cheers
Mathias

```
<div id="MyDiv">
    <?php
        if(isset($_COOKIE["MyCookie"]) and $_COOKIE['MyCookie']==1){
            $file = triangle.png
        $id = tr;
        }
        else
        {
            $file = square.png;
            $id = sq;
        }
    ?>

    <a href="#" id="<?php echo "$id" ?>"><img src="<?php echo "$file" ?>"></a>
</div>

<script>
  jQuery(function() {
     jQuery("#tr").click(function(evt) {
        document.cookie="MyCookie=0";
        $('#MyDiv').load(local.href+'#MyDiv').
        evt.preventDefault();
     }),
     jQuery("#sq").click(function(evt) {
        document.cookie="MyCookie=1";
        $('#MyDiv').load(local.href+'#MyDiv').
        evt.preventDefault();
     });
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way would be by using [cookies.js](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/src/jquery.cookie.js) which lets you get cookies in jQuery.

Here's a very simple example code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="triangle.png" alt="Picture" class="image" id="triangle" />
    <input type="button" value="Load picture" id="load-picture" />
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
/** Wait until jQuery is ready */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#load-picture").click(function() {
        var image = jQuery(".image");
        var cookie_content = jQuery.cookie("MyCookie");
        /** Change the picture accordingly */
        if(cookie_content.length >= 1) {
            jQuery(image).attr("src", "square.png").attr("id", "square");
        }
        else {
            jQuery(image).attr("src", "triangle.png").attr("id", "triangle");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```